# Jquery scroller causing horizontal scrolling issue on all browsers

Tags: c#, jquery

I'm having horizontal scrolling issues and i'm thinking my jquery for the slider is causing the issue. Go to  and you'll see the issue. It is difficult to show the code since I have no idea what to fix.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is at fault:

```
<div id="loadingSpinner_v0" class="playerLoadingSpinner" style="width: 32px; height: 32px; position: absolute; top: 277px; left: 40px;">
<div id="loadingSpinner_v1" class="playerLoadingSpinner" style="width: 32px; height: 32px; position: absolute; top: 277px; left: 1040px;">
<div id="loadingSpinner_v2" class="playerLoadingSpinner" style="width: 32px; height: 32px; position: absolute; top: 277px; left: 2040px;">
<div class="loadingSpinner"></div>
</div>
<div id="loadingSpinner_v3" class="playerLoadingSpinner" style="width: 32px; height: 32px; position: absolute; top: 277px; left: 40px;">
<div id="loadingSpinner_v4" class="playerLoadingSpinner" style="width: 32px; height: 32px; position: absolute; top: 277px; left: 40px;">
```

Note that all of these spinners are positioned far to the right.  It looks like these are added/used by the mwEmbed-player and absolutely positioned on the page, rather than on the element they are associated with.

BTW, I found this by opening firebug, scrolling a bit to the right, and then hovering over elements in the HTML tab until I saw something that extended into the right area.

Comment: Yeah I found the area. I'm thinking it's from the media player I added in. I'll find the it sooner or later haha. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, it's from the mwEmbed player.